# flask, flask table and peewee select not populating flask table correctly

Tags: mysql, flask, peewee

Working in windows 10, python 3, flask, flask table, peewee, mysql db and using straight out of the box code, but getting the following

[image: table in web application]

Simple peewee model coding

```
db = MySQLDatabase('proposalexperiments', user='root',
    passwd='Emerson#20', host='localhost' )

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Users(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(null=False)
    firstname = TextField
    lastname = TextField   
    username = TextField
    password = TextField
    email= TextField

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

def find_all_users():
    query = Users.select()
    return query
```

simple flask coding to select profile page showing logged in user information and all user information in a table

```
@app.route('/proposal-experiments/profile')
def profile():

    # Check if user is loggedin
    if 'loggedin' in session:
        # We need logged users info for the user so we can display it on the profile page
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = %s', [session['username']])
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # We need all the users info
        users = find_all_users()
        table = TableUsers(users)
        #table.border = True
        # Show the profile page with account info
        return render_template('profile.html', account=account, table=table)

    # User is not loggedin redirect to login page
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I am new to flask so I might be making a rookie error, but after looking at examples and scripts

Comment: You're showing your password dog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use field *instances*, not the classes themselves.

```
firstname = TextField  # this is wrong!
```

Do this:

```
firstname = TextField()
```